# Call API automatically to fetch data with prop value when component is displayed in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a page which displays a list of mutual funds. With each mutual fund, I have a button to display their NAV history. This button calls a component which has an embedded API call to fetch the NAV history. I pass the fund code for which the data is to be fetched as a prop to the component. However, I am not able to trigger the API call automatically when the prop is called.

this is my code as of now:

Parent component (main page):

```
<template>
   <!-- some code -->
      <a href="#" @click="fetchNavHistory(fund)">
          <v-icon small>history</v-icon>
      </a>
   <!-- some more code -->

   <NAVHistory 
      :show="showNavHistory"
      :amfi_code="amfi_code"
      ref="history"
      @hide="showNavHistory=false"
   />

</template>

export default {
  name: "FundList",
  components: {
      NAVHistory
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showNavHistory: false,
      amfi_code: 0
    }
  },
  methods:{
   fetchNavHistory(fund){
      this.amfi_code = fund.amfi_code
      this.showNavHistory = true
      var child = this.$refs.history
      child.fetchNavHistory()
    }
  }
}
```

Child component (where NAV history is displayed):

```
<template>
    <!-- some code -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        show: Boolean,
        amfi_code: Number
    },
    data(){
        return{
            apiURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASEURL,
            navHistory: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchNavHistory(){
            try{
              const response = await fetch(this.apiURL + '/navhistory', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({"amfi_code": this.amfi_code}),
                headers: {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
            })
              const data = await response.json()
              console.log(data)
              this.navHistory = data
            } catch(error){
              console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

At first I tried calling the `fetchNavHistory()` method on `updated()` event. But that kept calling the API non-stop when the component was displayed on the screen.

Then I tried adding a `watch` for the `show` prop. But that didn't work at all.

Finally, as a workaround, I called the API from the parent component itself. While that is working, it is calling the component with the previous value of the amfi_code, rather than the updated value. So the first time it gets called, the amfi_code is passed as 0.

Is there a way to safely trigger the API call when the component is displayed, i.e., the `show` prop is set to true?

Comment: You can tyr watch with `deep:true` option that way the watch will be triggered when a component will be mounted. Or you can call API on `mounted` hook and check `show` prop in it

Comment: The `deep:true` was what I needed. Otherwise the watch wasn't triggering the call. What does this do exactly? I also had to add `immediate:true` otherwise it wasn't triggering the first time when the prop was just initialised.
If you wrote this as an answer, I could mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try watch with **deep:true** option that way the watch will be triggered when a component will be mounted. Or you can call API on mounted hook and check show prop in it.

**deep:true** means a watch will look at if changes occur not only for a watched prop but additionally at all nested props.

**immediate:true** means that a watch will fire after a component is mounted (when a watched prop has initial value).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Even though I had figured out what to do, I had not understood what the deep and immediate parameters were doing. Now it's clear.